# should response headers (i.e. 400) be used to indicate errors (particularily with x-editable)

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, x-editable

Using the http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ plugin.  Upon posting a result, it has two callbacks:  `error` and `success`.

`error` will be triggered whenever the server doesn't respond with a 200 header.  As such, the server could validate some data, and upon failure, provide a 400 response with some associated text which will be received by the client.  I don't think JavaScript tracking solutions such as qbaka/GA/etc will log 400 status responses as errors, but still not positive.

`success`, on the other hand, will be will be triggered whenever the server responds with a 200 header, and JSON could be returned which contains error status, etc, eliminating the need to use the `error` callback.

Is one approach more appropriate than the other?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer lies in the goals and architecture of a RESTful service:-

[As stated in this article by IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/)

> One of the key characteristics of a RESTful Web service is the explicit use of HTTP methods in a way that follows the protocol as defined by RFC 2616

There is a great resource [here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) which explains the intended use of HTTP Status Codes, way too much to copy into my response but for a 400 code here's an explanation:-

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Comment: Thanks Kane,  Great links!  One concern is that the client submits some data, but doesn't validate because it is not unique in the DB.  Then a record was deleted in the DB so the original request will be unique.  But, the client will not repeat the request because of the previous 400 code.  Valid concern?